# Join the same table based on a same column

Tags: sql

I have two tables users and articles. The modified_by column in the Books table holds the corresponding users id who modified it. The user_id column in the Books table is the author. Both user_id and modified_by of the books table look to the id in the users table.

```
create table USERS (id int, name varchar(55));
insert into USERS values
( 1, 'person1'),
( 2, 'person2');



create table BOOKS (id int, user_id int, modified_by int);
insert into BOOKS values
(1, 2, 2),
(2, 2, 2),
(3, 2, 2),
(4, 1, 2);
```

My task is to display the books with name of the user in both the modified_by and user_id columns after joining. So far I have joined and got the name in the user_id column. How can I do the same for the modified_by column as it currently just shows the id and not the name

Current query

```
SELECT
  books.id,
  books.user_id,
  users.name,
FROM
  books
INNER JOIN users ON
  books.user_id = users.id
```

Result required:

```
(1, person2, person2),
(2, person2, person2),
(3, person2, person2),
(4, person1, person2);
```

Comment: Is this mysql ? If yes please add it as tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***join*** the `users` table twice as

```
SELECT b.id, u1.name AS user_id, u2.name AS modified_by
  FROM books b
  JOIN users u1
    ON b.user_id = u1.id
  JOIN users u2  
    ON b.modified_by = u2.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fk773fph)</kbd>

*Indeed, it's better to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` if existence of non-matching values among tables is the case*

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for would be this. I haven't done SQL in a while so there could be some syntax errors :), but it should be in the ballpark.

```
SELECT
  b.id,
  u1.name,
  u2.name
FROM
  books as b
INNER JOIN users as u1 ON
  b.user_id = u1.id
INNER JOIN users as u2 ON
  b.modified_by = u2.id
```

Comment: it is `u1.name, u2.name` not `u1.id, u2.id`. BTW: You should check your answer before posting it. And you are right. You have a syntax error

Comment: I apologise for the oversight on the name/id, that should have been avoided. As for the syntax, they did not specify which version of SQL it is and I do not have an SQL environment set up on my current workstation. I am always willing to learn though, what is the syntax error, as I don't immediately see it?

Comment: You can use online envirements like [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/). Looks like have found the syntax error, which will be an error in all SQL versions

Comment: Yes, it was a stupid oversight. Thank you for correcting me. And thank you for sharing the online environment, I didn't know that existed for SQL :)

Answer (score 0):

You can join the users table twice :

```
SELECT
  b.id,
  u1.name as `user`,
  u2.name as modified_by
FROM
  BOOKS b 
INNER JOIN USERS u1 ON b.user_id = u1.id
INNER JOIN USERS u2 ON b.modified_by = u2.id;
```

Try it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/I1KzRNSs